# Eclipse unhandle loop exception

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to Eclipse.
Every once in a while, I get this error message

https://i.stack.imgur.com/74ZP3.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUJ8h.jpg

Please click on links to see images !

Thanks

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message

Comment: What is your question? Did you Google the errors to find out more about them?

Comment: There is a workaround. Change the Java editor to WindowBuilder. Eclipse->Windows->Preferences->File Associations choose WindowBuilder Editor as Java default edito

Comment: @CodelsLife
I already have that set and I am still getting that error !

Comment: @greg-449
The error log shows:
Unhandled event loop exception
No more handles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens for two reasons,
1. improper updates of eclipse internal jar/s
2. Intermittent project issues

For 2, Go to project>Clean and clean all projects. (Ensure Build Automatically is selected) If persists restart eclipse.

For 1, close Eclipse IDE , navigate to eclipse folder location in your machine, eclipse>plugins>find org.eclipse.ui* folder/jar

remove that jar(take a backup and keep in another location)

Now start eclipse, It will update that jar which will solve the issue

Comment: Thank you for the help !